# Webservice call web method

Tags: c#, web-services, webservice-client

i have webservice with one method which recieves xml as string:

```
[WebMethod]
public int Catch_string(string str)
{  
}
```

how can i send xml file to this method from win forms?

why doesn't it work^

```
HttpWebRequest req = 
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/test/service.asmx");
       req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
       req.Accept = "text/xml";
       req.Method = "POST";
       Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream();
       outXml.Save(stm);
       stm.Close();
```

Comment: Why don't you just generate a web service proxy using Visual Studio (Add Web Reference) and invoke the web service that way?

Comment: i added reference to web service, what is next? and i didnt say that this web method saves this files on server, btw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a webreference to your winforms application and use the generated proxy class to invoke the webservice.

Checkout this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/cpwebserviceconsumer.aspx) for implementation details.